# CoreGraphics for retina display

Tags: iphone, core-graphics, retina-display, cg

I am using the following code to perform some manipulations on the image that I loaded, but I find that the display becomes blurry when it is on the retina display

```
- (UIImage*)createImageSection:(UIImage*)image section:(CGRect)section

{
float originalWidth = image.size.width ;
float originalHeight = image.size.height ;
int w = originalWidth * section.size.width;
int h = originalHeight * section.size.height;

CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, w, h, 8, w * 8,CGImageGetColorSpace([image CGImage]), kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
CGContextClearRect(ctx, CGRectMake(0, 0, originalWidth * section.size.width, originalHeight * section.size.height)); // w + h before
CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, (float)-originalWidth * section.origin.x, (float)-originalHeight * section.origin.y);
CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0, 0, originalWidth, originalHeight), [image CGImage]);
CGImageRef cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);
UIImage* resultImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:cgImage];

CGContextRelease(ctx);
CGImageRelease(cgImage);

return resultImage;
}
```

How do I change this to make it retina compatible.

Thanks in advance for your help

Best,
DV

Answer (score 48, accepted):

CGImages don't take into account the Retina-ness of your device, so you have to do so yourself.

To do that, you need to multiply all of your coordinates and sizes that use in CoreGraphics routines by the input image's `scale` property (which will be 2.0 on Retina devices), to ensure you do all your manipulation at double resolution.

Then you need to change the initialization of `resultImage` to use `initWithCGImage:scale:orientation:` and input the same scale factor. This is what makes Retina devices render the output at native resolution rather than pixel-doubled resolution.

Comment: If you change the CTM (current transform matrix) of your context by calling `CGContextScaleCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 2, 2)`, you don't need to manually multiply your coordinates, you can just draw the same as you would with non-retina images.

Comment: Sorry, was too quick with the comment and too late for the edit. If you do it like this, you don't need to think of scaling all the coordinates yourself: `CGFloat scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]; CGContextScaleCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), scale, scale);`

Comment: So much yes. Great solution.

Comment: Still have to manually fix the scale if you draw only a portion (a sub rect) inside that image.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for the answer, helped me! Anyway to be clearer, the code by OP should be changed like this:

```
- (UIImage*)createImageSection:(UIImage*)image section:(CGRect)section        
{
    CGFloat scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]; ////// ADD

    float originalWidth = image.size.width ;
    float originalHeight = image.size.height ;
    int w = originalWidth * section.size.width *scale; ////// CHANGE
    int h = originalHeight * section.size.height *scale; ////// CHANGE

    CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, w, h, 8, w * 8,CGImageGetColorSpace([image CGImage]), kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
    CGContextClearRect(ctx, CGRectMake(0, 0, originalWidth * section.size.width, originalHeight * section.size.height)); // w + h before
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, (float)-originalWidth * section.origin.x, (float)-originalHeight * section.origin.y);

    CGContextScaleCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), scale, scale); ////// ADD

    CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0, 0, originalWidth, originalHeight), [image CGImage]);
    CGImageRef cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);
    UIImage* resultImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:cgImage];

    CGContextRelease(ctx);
    CGImageRelease(cgImage);

    return resultImage;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift version :

```
    let scale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale

    CGContextScaleCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), scale, scale)
```